# Calculate range of variable types in C

Tags: c, void-pointers, kernighan-and-ritchie

a hobbyist here so sorry for the nooby question. K&R ex. 2-1. Use header constants and/or direct computation to calculate range of various variable types (char, short, int, long) + floating types. I used limits.h constants to print the range of fixed width variable types for reference. And I still have to check IEEE754.

My max functions gives me 1 less for the desired result, like: 0xfe, 0xfffe, etc so the LSB for some reason is not toggled to 1. Why is that? Yesterday, while thinking on the problem, I came up with the idea to use void* type to pass the various variable types to min-max functions. To be able to derefence void* type storing addresses of fixed width numbers with different length, I had the idea to simply cast it to size_t* type, and somehow it works, and I don't know why. Is this even legal, I've never seen it in my C programming books. If it is not legal, what other possibilites does one have to derefence void* type?

I do not wish to use loops and check overflows, that method is very slow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>

void unsigned_max(void* data_ptr, size_t data_size) {
    int bit = ((int)data_size * 8) - 1;

    while(bit) {
        *(size_t*)data_ptr |= 1 << bit;
        bit--;
    }
}

void unsigned_min(void* data_ptr, size_t data_size) {
    int bit = ((int)data_size * 8) - 1;

    while(bit){
        *(size_t*)data_ptr &= 0 << bit;
        bit--;
    }
}

void signed_min(void* data_ptr, size_t data_size) {
    int bit = ((int)data_size * 8) - 1;
    *(size_t*)data_ptr |= 1 << bit;
    bit--;

    while (bit) {
        *(size_t*)data_ptr |= 0 << bit;
        bit--;
    }
}

void signed_max(void* data_ptr, size_t data_size) {
    int bit = ((int)data_size * 8) - 1;
    *(size_t*)data_ptr &= 0 << bit;
    bit--;

    while (bit) {
        *(size_t*)data_ptr |= 1 << bit;
        bit--;
    }
}

int main(void) {

    unsigned char u_byte = 0;
    char byte = 0;
    unsigned short ushort_intgr = 0;
    short short_intgr = 0;
    unsigned int u_intgr = 0;
    int intgr = 0;
    unsigned long ulong_intgr = 0;
    long long_intgr = 0;

    char str_output[18] = "Min-max range of";
    char delimiter[18] =  "================";

    /*
     * Print ranges of unsigned and signed instances of char, short, int and long
     * variables using limits.h constants.
     */
    
    printf("%s unsigned char:\n%x,%x\n", str_output, u_byte, UCHAR_MAX);
    printf("%s signed char:\n%x,%x\n", str_output, CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);
    printf("%s unsigned short:\n%x,%x\n", str_output, ushort_intgr, USHRT_MAX);
    printf("%s signed short:\n%x,%x\n", str_output, SHRT_MIN, SHRT_MAX);
    printf("%s unsigned int:\n%x,%x\n", str_output, u_intgr, UINT_MAX);
    printf("%s signed int:\n%x,%x\n", str_output, INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
    printf("%s unsigned long:\n%x,%x\n", str_output, ulong_intgr, ULONG_MAX);
    printf("%s signed long:\n%x,%x\n", str_output, LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX);
    
    
    printf("%s\n", delimiter);

    /*
     * Print ranges of unsigned and signed instances of char, short, int and long
     * variables using bitwise operations.
     */

    printf("%s unsigned char:\n%d,", str_output, u_byte);
    unsigned_max(&u_byte, sizeof(u_byte));
    printf("%x\n", u_byte);

    printf("%s signed char:\n", str_output);
    signed_min(&u_byte, sizeof(u_byte));
    printf("%x,", u_byte);
    signed_max(&u_byte, sizeof(u_byte));
    printf("%x\n", u_byte);

    printf("%s unsigned short:\n%d,", str_output, ushort_intgr);
    unsigned_max(&ushort_intgr, sizeof(ushort_intgr));
    printf("%x\n", ushort_intgr);

    printf("%s signed short:\n", str_output);
    signed_min(&short_intgr, sizeof(short_intgr));
    printf("%x,", short_intgr);
    signed_max(&short_intgr, sizeof(short_intgr));
    printf("%x\n", short_intgr);

    printf("%s unsigned int:\n%u,", str_output, u_intgr);
    unsigned_max(&u_intgr, sizeof(u_intgr));
    printf("%x\n", u_intgr);

    printf("%s signed int:\n", str_output);
    signed_min(&intgr, sizeof(intgr));
    printf("%x,", intgr);
    signed_max(&intgr, sizeof(intgr));
    printf("%x\n", intgr);

    printf("%s unsigned long:\n%lu,", str_output, ulong_intgr);
    unsigned_max(&ulong_intgr, sizeof(ulong_intgr));
    printf("%x\n", ulong_intgr);

    printf("%s signed long:\n", str_output);
    signed_min(&long_intgr, sizeof(long_intgr));
    printf("%x,", long_intgr);
    signed_max(&long_intgr, sizeof(long_intgr));
    printf("%x\n", long_intgr);

    return 0;
}
```

My output is:

```
Min-max range of unsigned char:
0,ff
Min-max range of signed char:
ffffff80,7f
Min-max range of unsigned short:
0,ffff
Min-max range of signed short:
ffff8000,7fff
Min-max range of unsigned int:
0,ffffffff
Min-max range of signed int:
80000000,7fffffff
Min-max range of unsigned long:
0,ffffffff
Min-max range of signed long:
80000000,7fffffff
================
Min-max range of unsigned char:
0,fe
Min-max range of signed char:
fe,7e
Min-max range of unsigned short:
0,fffe
Min-max range of signed short:
ffff8000,7ffe
Min-max range of unsigned int:
0,fffffffe
Min-max range of signed int:
80000000,7ffffffe
Min-max range of unsigned long:
0,fffffffe
Min-max range of signed long:
80000000,7ffffffe
```

I also looked at the K&R solution book, the writers solve usually everything with elegant one-liners. It doesn't seem to work when I run it, giving back zeroes for min and max values. I know that -0 is every bit is true in one's complement form. That time -0 could have been stored as 0x1111? So 0x1111 >> 1 = 0x0111; 0x0111*(-1) = 0x1000?

```
printf("signed char min = %d\n", -(char)((unsigned char) -0 >> 1));
printf("signed char max = %d\n", (char)((unsigned char) -0 >> 1));
printf("unsigned char max = %u\n", (unsigned char) -0);
...
```

Comment: Taking signed short as an example, `ffff8000` can't be correct because it has 4 bytes rather than 2. The lower 2 bytes are fine though.

Comment: That should be ~0, not -0 (at least on a two's complement machine).

Comment: Ah that makes sense, my pdf copy of the solutions book is of very poor quality.

Comment: ...except that's not enough, giving -127 and 127

Comment: change `while (bit)` to `while (bit >= 0)`, because 1 is `1 << 0`.

Comment: @mevets thanks, this way I get good max values, loop never had the chance at lsb bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a two's complement machine, you need

```c
printf("signed char min:        %hhd\n", -(signed char)((unsigned char)~0 >> 1) - 1);
printf("signed char max:        %hhd\n", (signed char)((unsigned char)~0 >> 1));
printf("unsigned char max:      %hhu\n", (unsigned char)~0);

printf("signed short min:       %hd\n", -(signed short)((unsigned short)~0 >> 1) - 1);
printf("signed short max:       %hd\n", (signed short)((unsigned short)~0 >> 1));
printf("unsigned short max:     %hu\n", (unsigned short)~0);

printf("signed int min:         %d\n", -(signed int)(~0U >> 1) - 1);
printf("signed int max:         %d\n", (signed int)(~0U >> 1));
printf("unsigned int max:       %u\n", ~0U);

printf("signed long min:        %ld\n", -(signed long)(~0UL >> 1) - 1);
printf("signed long max:        %ld\n", (signed long)(~0UL >> 1));
printf("unsigned long max:      %lu\n", ~0UL);

printf("signed long long min:   %lld\n", -(signed long long)(~0ULL >> 1) - 1);
printf("signed long long max:   %lld\n", (signed long long)(~0ULL >> 1));
printf("unsigned long long max: %llu\n", ~0ULL);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T548Y1K5j)

Note: `char` is not always the same as `signed char`, so we need to use `signed char`. We could, however, simply use `short` and `int` instead of `signed short` and `signed int`.

---

That said, the correct and platform-independent approach is to use the compiler-provided defines.

```c
#include <limits.h>

printf("signed char min:        %hhd\n", SCHAR_MIN);
printf("signed char max:        %hhd\n", SCHAR_MAX);
printf("unsigned char max:      %hhu\n", UCHAR_MAX);

printf("signed char min:        %hd\n", SHRT_MIN);
printf("signed char max:        %hd\n", SHRT_MAX);
printf("unsigned char max:      %hu\n", USHRT_MAX);

printf("signed int min:         %d\n", INT_MIN);
printf("signed int max:         %d\n", INT_MAX);
printf("unsigned int max:       %u\n", UINT_MAX);

printf("signed long min:        %ld\n", LONG_MIN);
printf("signed long max:        %ld\n", LONG_MAX);
printf("unsigned long max:      %lu\n", ULONG_MAX);

printf("signed long long min:   %lld\n", LLONG_MIN);
printf("signed long long max:   %lld\n", LLONG_MAX);
printf("unsigned long long max: %llu\n", ULLONG_MAX);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xcPseenjc)

Comment: Added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Could you just please tell me 1 more, if dereferencing a void* type in a way that it is casted to size_t* type is allowed?

Comment: You can't dereference a `void*`, or at least not usefully. You can cast a `void*` to a `size_t*` and dereference that, but the behaviour is only defined if it actually points to a value of type `size_t`.